# How can I model a rotating system which does not have constant acceleration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I've sampled a rotating system to come up with a list of positions and velocities at certain times. I want to be able to predict how long it will take to reach a certain speed and how far it will have rotated in that time. I can't use the standard equations of angular motion because the acceleration isn't constant. The acceleration seems to have a quadratic relationship with velocity.

What sort of approach should I use to go about solving this? Thank you

Comment: Which direction is the quadratic?  Is it $a \propto v^2, v \propto a^2, a \propto v^{-2}$?

Comment: From an excel line of best fit, a = -0.0162v^2 + 0.3494v - 2.1517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to write $\frac {dv}{dt}=-0.0162v^2 + 0.3494v - 2.1517$ and get $t+C=\int \frac {dv}{-0.0162v^2 + 0.3494v - 2.1517}$